# how to go from eagle design to Part list

Tags: eaglecad, cad

I am looking for a maintainable, shareable and scalable process to output a complete part list (as in "Part N°XXX from supplier YYY") From an Eagle project, when it seems to only be able to provides a BOM ("Component type XXX with value YYY").

Is there a way to do that using Eagle alone, or do i have to process the BOM, in excel for example?

Comment: Eagle does not allow to annotate devices with other things than an electrical value (and package type if you are willing to tune your libraries), so **no**.

Comment: Are you willing to spend some small amount of money and importing a CSV into a cheap stock-control/BoM data base?

Comment: No EDA tool should bear responsibility telling which supplier you will be using to purchase electronic components. Sourcing is your sole responsibility. If you mean *manufacturer* instead, then you can put complete P/N into the *value* field of the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attributes. There are also ULP's out there that use an external database.

But to be honest, eagle is the wrong tool for the job. If you are looking for that level of automation and integration, you should use a higher end tool.